# Eloquent Join With Pivot Table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a pivot table called `message_recipients` that looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `message_recipients` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `message_recipients_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  KEY `message_recipients_message_id_index` (`message_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `message_recipients_message_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`message_id`) REFERENCES `messages` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `message_recipients_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And then I have a `messages` table

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `messages_sender_id_index` (`sender_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `messages_sender_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=110 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And the default `user` table.

And I have the following classes

```
class MessageRecipients extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'message_recipients';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function message() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function me() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}

class Message extends Eloquent {
    public function recipients() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MessageRecipients');
    }

    public function sender() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

And I am trying to figure out how to generate the query. I have

```
$message = Message::with('App\Models\MessageRecipients')->where('message_recipients.user_id', '=', 1)->first();
```

But I keep getting an error about missing `message_recipients` column. How can I generate a query that would look like (or produce the same data as)

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
    messages
JOIN
    message_recipients
ON
    messages.id = message_recipients.message_id
WHERE
    message_recipients.user_id = 1
```

Or basically select all the messages with message_recipients data that are assigned to that user.

Comment: Use a [many-to-many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many).

Comment: 1 `with` accepts relation (method name), not model name. 2 There are no `joins` when you eager load stuff (`with`). 3 Use `whereHas` to filter by related table, or instead find the user then call `$user->messages` to get all the messages that belong to him. And of course use `belongsToMany` for m-m relation as @Cryode already mentioned (you might want to add `id` field to that pivot table as well - Eloquent uses this one).